# Grunt uglifying step failing

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I am new to Grunt and I am trying to use it with this config

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Define our source and build folders
    js_src_path: 'javascripts',
    js_build_path: "build/js",

// Grunt Tasks
    concat: {
      options:{
        separator: ';'
      },
      js: {
        src: ['<%= js_src_path %>/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= js_build_path %>/app.js'
      }    },
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
      },
      js: {
        src: '<%= concat.js.dest %>',
        dest:'<%= js_build_path %>/app.min.js'
      }
    }
    }
  );

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify']);
};
```

But I have this message :

```
Running "concat:js" (concat) task
File "build/js/app.js" created.

Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
>> Uglifying source "build/js/app.js" failed.
Warning: Uglification failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Is there anything wrong with my config ?

Thanks

Comment: This looks odd... the output you posted specifies it's trying to run `uglify:build`, but there is not target `build` in the `uglify` task in the Gruntfile you posted. Are you sure this is the output from that config? Also, it would be helpful to see the final config file, after the server tags have been (`<%= ... %>`) have been evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've probably moved on by now, but the uglify can fail if there was something wrong in the JavaScript. It's not as strict as say, JSHint, but if you simply have bad JS, uglify will have problems uglify-ing.

This can also happen because of a bad order of scripts (i.e. trying to load a jQuery plugin before jQuery, perhaps?).

Comment: But even following a tutorial on the well known repo of [jsbin](https://github.com/remy/jsbin/blob/master/docs/running-your-own-jsbin.md) is producing errors when attempting to "uglify"

Comment: It's "compact javascript" causing it to fail. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879546/grunt-uglifying-step-failing/26643807#26643807

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that grunt-contrib-uglify returns this error when compressing "semi-colon-less" or "compact" javascript.

This is legal javascript, but it doesn't even look (to me) like the same language! See the short example at the top of this bug report https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/issues/29.

For more information regarding this "compact style" see:
http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding

It would seem grunt-contrib-uglify should be able to handle any valid javascript - but it does not.